# Exercise on subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Find the greatest $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such as there exist distinct subsets $S_1,S_2,...,S_m\in[[1,n]]$ verifying $\forall i,j\in\left[|1,m|\right], i\neq j\Rightarrow  |S_i \cap S_j| = 1$

How would I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** This is a result of Fisher, which states that $m \leq n$. Use linear algebra on the incidence matrix.

Comment: What's an incidence matrix ?

Comment: Let the rows be the subsets, and the columns be the elements. Place a 1 if that subset contains the elements, and 0 otherwise.